# is the verb "possess" a one-off or a prolong action? Say "He is possessed" or "He was possessed"

Tags: meaning

In [oxford dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/possess?q=possess),

> [usually passive] possess somebody (literary) (of a feeling, an
>   emotion, etc.) to have a powerful effect on somebody and control the
>   way that they think, behave, etc.
>
> *A terrible fear possessed her.*

So, the verb "**possess**" in this meaning is a *one-off* or a *prolong* action?

Ok, let say, A ghost went into a soul of a man **yesterday**. The ghost is still inside the man at this moment.

So, we say "He is possessed" (if we think "**possess**" is a pro-long process. That is the process last from yesterday to now) or
 say "He was possessed" (if we think "**possess**" is a one-off process. That is the process happened yesterday only)

Comment: You ask if "possess" means "a one-off or a prolong(ed) action". But [*one-off*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/one-off) concerns a quantity, not a time frame. You should use a different word.

Comment: "Possess" is a stative verb as far as I know. "He is possessed = He is being controlled by" in your sentence. You can say that but you can't say, "The ghost is possesing him."

Comment: Look at the word "love" it acts in a similar way. He was loved - not any more. He is lovedd - now and in general. You can't say, "Somebody is loving him." Don't say that "I'm loving it" is correct.

Comment: Only Induan English allows continuous tense of stative verbs. Though I often hear AmE and BrE do that in informal English. Like: I am understanding, knowing, smelling, tasting.

Answer (score 1):

"**[Possess](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/possess)**" means *(of a demon or spirit, especially an evil one) have complete power over (someone) and be manifested through their speech or actions*

If a ghost possessed a human's body yesterday then the human is still possessed today unless somebody performed the ritual of exorcism. If you want to refer to the past and tell someone when somebody got possessed then you can say "**He got possessed yesterday**" or "**The possession occurred yesterday**", maybe something like "**Something possessed him yesterday and is still in him**"